# SwiftUI:How to resize image in WidgetKit?

Tags: image, swiftui, widgetkit

I wanna add image to my custom widget, but I have problems with image!

My code:

```
  Image("space").resizable()
                .frame(width: 32.0, height: 32.0)
```

My error:
The body of the Widget entries' view contains an image of size (512.0, 106.0) which is beyond the maximum of (463.2, 196.79999999999998)

What should I do in this case? Thanks!